# Python Object Lifetime Characteristics

Tags: python, oop, posix, scrapy

Note : if you know of any (non-elaborate) library code that does what I want please enlighten a C/C++ programmer, I'll accept that as answer.

I have a global variable set to an instance of the following class. It's purpose is to allow me to set some manual interruption points to place some quick and dirty `printf` style debug points in a scrapy spider (I specifically need to break when certain criteria are met to tune a parser, there are some extremely rare input data anomalies) -- Adapted from [this](http://docs.python.org/faq/library#id12).

Os is OS X 10.8.

```
import termios, fcntl, sys, os

class DebugWaitKeypress(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        self.oldterm = termios.tcgetattr(self.fd)
        self.newattr = termios.tcgetattr(self.fd)
        self.newattr[3] = self.newattr[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO
        termios.tcsetattr(self.fd, termios.TCSANOW, self.newattr)

        self.oldflags = fcntl.fcntl(self.fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
        fcntl.fcntl(self.fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, self.oldflags | os.O_NONBLOCK)

    def wait(self):
        sys.stdin.read(1)

    def __del__(self):
        print "called del"
        termios.tcsetattr(self.fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, self.oldterm)
        fcntl.fcntl(self.fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, self.oldflags)
```

When I press Ctrl-C and the process is unwinding I get the following exception :

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tcsetattr'" in <bound method DebugWaitKeypress.__del__ of <hon.spiders.custom_debug.DebugWaitKeypress object at 0x108985e50>> ignored
```

I'm missing something about the mechanics of object lifetimes I guess ? How do remedy the situation. AFAIK any class instances should be destroyed before the imported code does, no ? in reverse order of declaration/definition.

I would just ignore this if the terminal wasn't screwed up after the process exits :D

**edit:**

Delian's comment on seth's answer led me to understand that I need to use a C `main()` like function, or any other function/generator which dominates as a root function and initialise the context there. This way When the process is going down the `__exit__` method of the context manager will get called. And I won't have to reprogram the terminal stream on each `wait()` call.

Although the cost of the reprogramming is potentially immaterial, it is good to know how one would these essential C/C++ semantics in python.

**edit 2:**

Twisted (which scrapy uses) goes apeshit when messing with stdin. So I had to solve the problem with file IO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long story short: `__del__` is useless for this purpose (and pretty much any other purpose; you should probably forget it exists). If you want deterministic cleanup, use a context manager.

> AFAIK any class instances should be destroyed before the imported code does, no ? in reverse order of declaration/definition.

That's C++. Forget it. Python does not care about this, in fact it does not even care about most things which are requirements for doing it. There is no such thing as a declaration in the entire Python language, and module-level variables are stored in what is essentially an unordered associative array. Variables do not store objects, they store references (which are *not* C++ references, they're basically pointers without pointer arithmetic) -- objects are on the heap and don't know a thing about variables, bindings, statements, or order of statements.

Moreover, when an objects is garbage collected, and *whether it is gc'd at all*, is undefined. You get a *mostly* deterministic picture in CPython due to reference counting, but even there it falls down the second you have cycles. The consequence is that `__del__` may be called at any point in time (including when half of the module is already torn down) or not at all. Multiple objects defining `__del__` referencing each other are also trouble, although some GCs try hard to do the right thing.

Bottom line is, you can assume very little at the time `__del__` runs, so you can't do very much. You get a last shot at disposing resources that should have been cleaned up via another method but weren't, and that's pretty much it. Rule of thumb: *Never* rely on it for *anything* mandatory.

Instead, create a [context manager and use it via `with`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). You get deterministic cleanup, without worrying about object lifetime. Because, truth to be told, object lifetime and resource lifetime are two entirely different things, and only entangled in C++ because it's the best way to do resource management *in that environment*. In Python, RAII does not apply, instead we have this:

```
with <context manager> as var:
    # do something
# "context closed", whatever that means - for resources, usually cleanup
```

By the way, you can define it far more conveniently via [contextlib](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) (quickly transliterated from your version, may contain errors or ugliness):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def debug_wait_keypress():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    oldterm = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    newattr = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    newattr[3] = newattr[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, newattr)
    oldflags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, oldterm)
        fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags)
```

Your `wait` method becomes a free function.

Answer (score 4):

If `__del__` is called, it happens sometime after the object's reference count is zero, and possibly not until the program ends, and not in any particular order. You also can't depend on anything external (especially globals) being available in `__del__`.

In your case, python cleaned up the reference to the `termios` module before it called `DebugWaitKeyPress.__del__`. That's why you're getting the `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tcsetattr'` message. `termios` is `None` by the time you try to use it.

I would guess you would be better off implementing a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager), and put your `__del__` code in `__exit__`.

Then you would be able to say something like:

```
with DebugWaitKeypress(...) as thing:
    do_something_with_it(thing)
# here, __exit__() is called to do cleanup
```

From the [`object.__del__` docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> Due to the precarious circumstances under which __del__() methods are
>   invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and
>   a warning is printed to sys.stderr instead. Also, when __del__() is
>   invoked in response to a module being deleted (e.g., when execution of
>   the program is done), other globals referenced by the __del__() method
>   may already have been deleted or in the process of being torn down
>   (e.g. the import machinery shutting down). For this reason, __del__()
>   methods should do the absolute minimum needed to maintain external
>   invariants. Starting with version 1.5, Python guarantees that globals
>   whose name begins with a single underscore are deleted from their
>   module before other globals are deleted; if no other references to
>   such globals exist, this may help in assuring that imported modules
>   are still available at the time when the __del__() method is called.

Comment: hmm are there any other constructs possible with context managers ? The documentation seems to suggest the construct be used for statement blocks. Which means each time I want to hit a breakpoint I have to reconfigure the terminal twice.

Comment: @HassanSyed You seem to underestimate it. As *anything* (even friggin' imports and class definitions, though you'd be hard-pressed to find a good usecase) can go inside a context manager, you could, for instance, wrap the call to your `main` function in one, and it'd configure the terminal before anything happens, and resets the configuration only when `main` is left (normally *or* due to an exception). Just like you could create a `DebugWaitKeypress` on the stack in `main` in C++.

Comment: Hmm that is the insight I needed I think. I could initialise a global with the class during scrapy's `parse` method implemented as a generator, I start the context at the top of the generator and then when I run out of url's to return the generator goes out of scope take the class down with it before scrapy begins shutting down.